# Have Screen Door that doesn't fit in rail frame

Tags: doors, outdoor, door-frame, sliding-glass-door, screens

Recently rented a home and the screen door was taken off by the previous rentee. I want to put it back but when I tried, I noticed that the screen door's frame was taller than the rail frame that it was meant for. More specifically, the "frame edge guards" are preventing me from putting back the screen door. I have been told that this is the original door, so it must have fit at one point. Am I doing something wrong? Image below to better showcase the issue I am facing with the screen door being too big for the frame. Any help or advice greatly appreciated.[image]

Edit: The wheels were taken off when I took this photo

Comment: Are there small wheels on that screen door(does it slide)?  It is possible that it just needs to be pushed up high enough to slip over, it might take some force.